# How to force a new line at the end of a file in Xcode

Tags: macos, xcode

According [to this site](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/no-newline-at-end-of-file), text files (i.e. source code files) should always end in a new line. But Xcode (as of at least version 7.1) defaults to have no new line at the end of a file unless you explicitly put it there.

There are preferences to strip trailing whitespace and set the default line endings (all in “Xcode -> Preferences -> Text Editing”) but I can’t find a way to automatically add a new line at the end of each file. Can this be done in Xcode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While this answer is written nearly a year after the question, I'll post it regardless for reference.

Xcode 8 and later automatically appends a newline to every saved text file if it didn't end with one. This includes files other than source code, like Markdown. There doesn't seem an option to *disable* this behaviour.

Comment: Thank you! I'd like to wait until it's released publicly before I accept it, but this is definitely the result I was looking for.